# "Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?" - Python error on Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: python, wxpython, ubuntu-18.04, hyper-v

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Windows Hyper-V virtual machine.

I have a GUI script built with Gooey, and Gooey uses wxpython in the background.

The GUI script runs fine in windows, but when I switch over to the Ubuntu virtual machine, I get this error:

`Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?`

There is no other stack trace.

I have googled for hours and found no solution.

Does anybody have experience with wxpython or Gooey on a HyperV ubuntu environment?

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What's the output of `echo $DISPLAY`?

Comment: Output is: `:10.0`

Comment: Check the output of `echo $XAUTHORITY` and ensure that `you` are the owner of that file. It should be  equivalent to `$HOME/.Xauthority` with permissons 600

Comment: As there has been no response, I'll assume the previous comment didn't provide a result. If you're attempting to run this script as superuser, newer versions PolicyKit-1 can fail for security purposes. Try running `xhost +` before running your script. (remember to turn it back off again afterwards)

Comment: @RolfofSaxony apologies I haven't been on the machine since posting the question. I will check and report back during the week. Thanks for the help.